# ggplot2 R fix x-axis label at a specific point relative to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis, fixed

Say I have a plot like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Test label")
```

Does `ggplot2` allow for fixing the `xlab` positioning at a specific point? Say I wanted the label to appear centered at the point where `x = 7` (rather than the default centering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you want, but you can adjust the horizontal justification in the `theme` options. This is **relative** between 0 and 1, not tied to the data coordinates. `0` is left-justified (left side of the axis), `1` is right-justified, and the default `0.5` as centered. In this case, we can set `hjust = 0.7`. (Though an axis from 1 to 10 has length 10 - 1 = 9, so we could get nitpicky and use `(7 - 1) / (10 - 1) = 2/3`... I'll leave it to you how precise you want to be.)

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Test label") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0.7))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gregor! This should do the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way, but the one from @Gregor Thomas is nicer

```r
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, label = 'Test label')

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  xlab('')             # no x-label
  #xlab("Test label")

p + geom_text(aes(label = label, x = 7, y = -Inf), vjust = 3) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')    # This keeps the labels from disappearing
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response as well! As you say, I decided to go with Gregor's as it was a little more clean.

Comment: This is a nice way to actually use data coordinates - +1. You are overplotting, however (hence the weird bold look of the label). To avoid that, either set `check_overlap = TRUE` inside `geom_text`, or consider using `annotate(geom = "text", ...)` instead. (`annotate` is probably the more canonical way to do it.)